# how to install cmake-gui 3?

Tags: gui, cmake

I have cmake 3.2.2 but cmake-gui shows 2.8 and some packages can not be configured using cmake-gui because they asked for the new version.
is there away to install cmake-gui 3 or to make it recognize the last version installed?
Have a nice day!
Ibraheem

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is:

- Remove the old installed cmake

  ```
  sudo apt remove cmake
  ```
- Download and build the recent version using qt support. e.g.

  ```
  ./configure --qt-gui
  make -j5
  ```
- Make soft link to `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

The `cmake-qt-gui` package from repository depends on 2.8 `cmake`. To make it recognize 3.2.2. you could try to mess with symlinks by setting `cmake` 2.8 link to the new `cmake`. But I can't guarantee that it will work and doubt that it will have the same the functionality.

But if you build `cmake` from source, you can get new `cmake-gui`. Open `bootstrap` file, scroll down and set:

```
cmake_bootstrap_qt_gui="1"
```

Then configure, build and install `cmake`. It might be better to delete `cmake-qt-gui` 2.8 version first, as I am not sure what will happen if you have both.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 : Solution

Click On the link below which will download a deb package of cmake-qt-gui_3 you will need gdebi to install it :
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cmake/cmake-qt-gui_3.16.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

How Do I install gdebi package manager ?
Type The Following Command in your terminal :

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Once Installed you can now open the deb package with gdebi package manager..
And Install..

> 2 : Solution

Type The Following Commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo snap install cmake -classic
```

Once the installation completes, run the “`–version`” command below to see the CMake version installed in your system.

```
cmake --version
```

> 3 : Solution :

```
sudo snap install cmake
```

version `3.18.2`, or

```
sudo apt  install cmake
```

version `3.16.3-1ubuntu1`

See '`snap info cmake`' for additional versions.